# How to set a column in gridview as hyperlink which is autogenerated

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, gridview

I want to make the `gridview.columns[0]` as hyperlink. I tried so many work around mentioned in different sites. I am binding a `list<>` to the grid. and I need to make the first column as hyperlink and upon clicking that link, it should be redirected to a page with the corresponding item. 
Which event I need to use and how can I pass that value from the list?

Comment: is your gridview rows are autogenerated ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        var firstCell = e.Row.Cells[0];
        firstCell.Controls.Clear();
        firstCell.Controls.Add(new HyperLink { NavigateUrl = firstCell.Text, Text = firstCell.Text });
    }
}
```

Be warned that if you bind data to grid only first time page loaded then your changes will disappear.

Comment: Hi also i would like to know how to hide a column in gridview.
I have tried             if (e.Row.RowType != DataControlRowType.Pager)
            {
                e.Row.Cells[1].Visible = false;
            }
this one and it works but its give an error.

Answer (score 3):

You have to make that column as Template Column

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
  <ItemTemplate>
   <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" Text="test" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("fieldName", "show.aspx?ID={0}") %>'></asp:HyperLink>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```