# how to change dynamic grid string value into hyperlink mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

***  I have GridView in dynamic..i want to change the dynamic value into hyperlink..here is my code***

```
 foreach (GridViewRow gr in Gridview1.Rows)
                {
                    HyperLink hp = new HyperLink();
                    hp.Text = gr.Cells[25].Text;
                    hp.NavigateUrl = "https://chennaiuat.paynearby.in:2025/UploadFiles/SDFiles/DepositSlip/" + hp.Text;
                    hp.Text = "<a href='" + hp.NavigateUrl+"'> </a>";
                    gr.Cells[25].Text = hp.Text;
                }
```

Comment: getting value while running in breakpoint.but results not came in hyperlink.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set a column in gridview as hyperlink which is autogenerated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6277653/how-to-set-a-column-in-gridview-as-hyperlink-which-is-autogenerated)

Comment: its not working

Answer (score 1):

Change your code in this way:

```
hp.Text = Context.Server.HtmlDecode("<a href='" + hp.NavigateUrl+"'> </a>");
```

Comment: tq for ur replying..now its working fine..thanks again